# What version of MobileFirst Platform Test Workbench is compatible with Worklight 6.2.0.01

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, rational-test-workbench

I downloaded Rational Test Workbench Mobile Test Edition 8.6.0. 
What is a compatible version of MobileFirst Platform Test Workbench for Worklight 6.2.0.01. ?

I have downloaded the test Workbench found in the Eclipse Market place. When I try to upload .apk file for testing in workbench it is not uploading.

It is showing an error but I am unable to know what the error is as I am unable to see it. My initial guess is that it is a version issue of Mobile Test Bench or any other issue?

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse Marketplace always contains the latest versions of MobileFirst Platform Studio and MobileFirst Platform Test Workbench (6.3 and 8.6.0.1, respectively). Ideally you should move up to the latest versions of both. However, if you cannot and need to get an older version of Test Workbench, you'll need to download a zip file.

For Worklight 6.2.0 (datestamp June 2014), download [Mobile Test Workbench for Worklight 8.5.1.3](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/products/en/MobileFirstPlatform/mtww_eclipse_8.5.1.3.zip).

For Worklight 6.2.0.1 (datestamp Oct 2014), download [Mobile Test Workbench for Worklight 8.6](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/products/en/MobileFirstPlatform/mtww_eclipse_8.6.zip).

Comment: very helpful indeed! can you provide also a link where we can find all the previous version, please? thanks!