# Cannot upload apk to MobileFirst Test Workbench

Tags: android, eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-mtww

I am using Eclipse Juno (Service Release 2), IBM Worklight Studio v6.2.0.00 and IBM Mobilefirst Platform Test Workbench v8.6.0

What I am trying to do is to upload an apk from the Android environment of my Worklight Project to the Mobile Test Workbench but it keeps failing, giving me the following error:

```
com.ibm.rational.test.lt.core.moeb.utils.ProcessExec$ProcessExecException: Cannot exec command: 
[C:\PROGRA~2\Android\ANDROI~1\build-tools\21.0.0\aapt.exe p --no-crunch -F 
C:\Users\abhm\Desktop\WORKSP~1\METADA~1\PLUGIN~1\COMIBM~1.MOE\builds\A3E821~1\unsigned8260035661537229820.apk -0 arsc -A 
C:\Users\abhm\Desktop\WORKSP~1\METADA~1\PLUGIN~1\COMIBM~1.MOE\builds\A3E821~1\HipraLinkHipraLinkAndroid\assets 
C:\Users\abhm\Desktop\WORKSP~1\METADA~1\PLUGIN~1\COMIBM~1.MOE\builds\A3E821~1\HipraLinkHipraLinkAndroid\build\apk]
Exit code: -1073741819

Process error stream:

at com.ibm.rational.test.lt.core.moeb.utils.ProcessExec.processExitCode(ProcessExec.java:261)
at com.ibm.rational.test.lt.core.moeb.utils.ProcessExec.exec(ProcessExec.java:235)
at com.ibm.rational.test.lt.core.moeb.utils.ProcessExec.exec(ProcessExec.java:116)
at com.ibm.rational.test.lt.core.moeb.utils.ProcessExec.exec(ProcessExec.java:95)
at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.aaptPackage(AndrolibResources.java:443)
at brut.androlib.Androlib.buildApk(Androlib.java:515)
at brut.androlib.Androlib.build(Androlib.java:250)
at brut.androlib.Androlib.build(Androlib.java:213)
at com.ibm.rational.test.mobile.android.buildchain.tools.build.BuildWrapper.build(BuildWrapper.java:214)
at com.ibm.rational.test.mobile.android.buildchain.AndroidBuildChain.build(AndroidBuildChain.java:330)
at com.ibm.rational.test.lt.models.behavior.moeb.utils.BuildChainManager$Build.run(BuildChainManager.java:200)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have seen some answers of people that had the same problem and solutions but they did not work: I have tried to copy the zipalign.exe to the tools folder (where the android sdk is installed), the hotfix does not work because it is for a previous version of the MTW and I have already changed the JRE definition to point to JDK.

I have also tried to execute the line in the cmd and gave me the following error:

```
ERROR: 'C:\Users\abhm\Desktop\WORKSP~1\METADA~1\PLUGIN~1\COMIBM~1.MOE\builds\A3E
821~1\unsigned8260035661537229820.apk' exists (use '-f' to force overwrite)
```

And when I use the '-f' to fore overwrite, the aapt.exe (Android Asset Packaging Tool) crashes...

Is there any other suggestion? Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Can you mention the exact build number of the MTW plug-in thaty you're using? As well as the Android version used, i.e. is at aimed at Android 5.0?

Comment: Hi, yes, the MTW plugin build number is   8.6.0.v20141113_1647 and I am using an Android 4.4.2 to make tests. I have also tried to deploy the application from version 4.1.2 and 5.0 but none of them were successful.

Answer (score 1):

this is a defect in the Android SDK (see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77629). Please update your SDK. It should fix the problem
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Akash, If you are running with MTW 8.6.0, you'll want to move up to IBM Worklight Studio v6.2.0.1 (6.2.0.01-20141013). See [What Version of MobileFirst Platform Test Workbench is Compatible with Worklight 6.2.0.01](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28304979/what-version-of-mobilefirst-platform-test-workbench-is-compatible-with-worklight/28305569#28305569)

Comment: Barbara, I have tried to do that and I still get the same error. I have now updated my WL version to the one you suggested but I still get the same error. Is there anyone here who have experienced the same error or made it work with this version of WL ?